# Is the included sentence about party planning grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence, tech-writing

Is it correct to write the following?

> Since you have asked me about the planning of a farewell party for your English teacher, I’m happy to help you with some suggestions.

Is there any way to improve the sentance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Since you have asked me about the planning of a farewell party for your English teacher,I’m happy to help you with some suggestions.”

This is perfectly good if just a little long. There is **nothing** wrong with it. Some might suggest you leave out the comma but not me. I might go with “You're planning a farewell party for your English teacher. Since you have asked me I’m [I'll be] happy to help you with some suggestions.” Making two sentences out of this one makes it a bit easier to read or hear.

Comment: "**Your** planning a farewell party"? Really?

Comment: The planning belongs to me and so is possessive. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Hi Elliot! You *are* mistaken I'm afraid. "planning" is a *verb* here, so we don't want a possessive. It should be **You're**, which is short for *You are*. "You're planning a farewell party..." This is the Present Continuous tense. (It's explained nice and clearly [here](https://learnenglishkids.britishcouncil.org/grammar-practice/present-simple-and-present-continuous).) "Planning" **can** be a noun - *The planning was atrocious* - but in the sentence above it is a verb: I plan, you plan, he plans... I'm planning, you're planning, he's planning...

Comment: If only you had said so in the first place. I can see your quite correct.

Comment: *Now* you got it!